# Always asking product attribute is required

Tags: magento2

I have created dropdown attribute with values required 'No'. But in front end when I clicked 'add to cart' that dropdown shows error like 'this product is required'.

[image]

Comment: but your screenshot says values required YES, can you double check it?

Comment: @Hit's Ha, before I changed to yes, the value was NO. So in that time also it asking the same thing as field required.

Comment: did you run php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush command after your changes?

Comment: @Hit's yes i have run.

Comment: If you are using configurable product then you need to select product attribute as option in frontend.

Comment: @SukumarGorai How can I do this?